# Windows 8 contest - bounty tile awarded early

Tags: bug, bounty, windows-8-challenge

I've just started a bounty on a [windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) question and despite not having awarded the bounty, I got notified that I qualified for the award a bounty tile in the contest.

Should the wording be changed to say "start a bounty", or should I not get the award until I actually accept an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, when you start a bounty - you've awarded a bounty since at the end of bounty period, even if you *don't* award a bounty to a person, the system will automatically award the bounty to the qualifying answer.

But yes, I think "Start a bounty" is more correct, since that's when the tile is triggered.

Comment: But what if I start the bounty right before the contest ends, then the automatic award would happen outside the contest timeline. :P I get the idea though. :)

Comment: Setting a bounty on a question doesn't necessarily lose the bounty. Given the right circumstances, you only lose half (or none at all) of the reputation you've put up. The tile remains.